# Where can I find the IntelliJ SSH Remote Run Plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins, ssh

I want to connect to a server via SSH directly in IntelliJ IDEA. Google's first search result links to the IntelliJ IDEA help manual about "Running SSH Terminal". In this guide's first step I am told that IDEA includes the "SSH Remote Run" plugin which I can't either find any information on or find it in the plugin repository of the IntelliJ platform.

This is the meant section of the [manual page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/running-ssh-terminal.html):

> 1. Make sure the SSH Remote Run plugin is enabled. The plugin is bundled with IntelliJ IDEA and activated by default. If the plugin is not activated, enable it on the Plugins page of the Settings / Preferences Dialog as described in Enabling and Disabling Plugins.

Comment: This plug-in is indeed [bundled](http://i.imgur.com/sXJc2Bm.png). However, you need IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: The docs are nasty since the plugin is not found on the market.

Comment: Please note that only the professional version supports this feature while community one cannot.

Comment: Plugin is included by default from now on. More info at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-ssh-terminal.html